# Maven can't get dependency information, although jar is in place

Tags: maven, ant

During building of my project I get the following error from Ant/Maven:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\kmilyutin\git\siamprofiler\classpath.build.xml:41: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\kmilyutin\git\siamprofiler\classpath.build.xml:33: Unable to resolve artifact: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar': Cannot find parent: org.apache.commons:commons-parent for project: commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0 for project commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0
  commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0
```

At the same time, files associated with `commons-beanutils` are in the repository:`C:\Users\kmilyutin\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.8.0`
Could someone help to solve this issue?

**UPDATE:** I tried to remove directory `.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\` and to build again. Maven gave me the same error, but there are now just 2 files in the `1.8.0\` directory: `commons-beanutils-1.8.0.pom` and `commons-beanutils-1.8.0.pom.sha1`. The jar file  is missing for whatever reason, although I can find it in the central Maven repository.

Here is the debug output:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\kmilyutin\git\siamprofiler\classpath.build.xml:41: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\kmilyutin\git\siamprofiler\classpath.build.xml:33: Unable to resolve artifact: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar': Cannot find parent: org.apache.commons:commons-parent for project: commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0 for project commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0
  commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  maven2-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/),
  jboss-public-repository-group (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/)

Path to dependency: 
    1) com.sivis:siamprofiler:war:2.7.3-SNAPSHOT
    2) org.richfaces.framework:richfaces-api:jar:3.3.5-SNAPSHOT


    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask.doExecuteResolution(DependenciesTask.java:268)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask.doExecute(DependenciesTask.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.AbstractArtifactTask.execute(AbstractArtifactTask.java:751)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.ArtifactResolutionException: Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar': Cannot find parent: org.apache.commons:commons-parent for project: commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0 for project commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0
  commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  maven2-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/),
  jboss-public-repository-group (https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/)

Path to dependency: 
    1) com.sivis:siamprofiler:war:2.7.3-SNAPSHOT
    2) org.richfaces.framework:richfaces-api:jar:3.3.5-SNAPSHOT


    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:430)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:435)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.collect(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:74)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveTransitively(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.ant.DependenciesTask.doExecuteResolution(DependenciesTask.java:263)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.metadata.ArtifactMetadataRetrievalException: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar': Cannot find parent: org.apache.commons:commons-parent for project: commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0 for project commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0
    at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocatedProject(MavenMetadataSource.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocatedArtifact(MavenMetadataSource.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultArtifactCollector.java:387)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Cannot find parent: org.apache.commons:commons-parent for project: commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0 for project commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1396)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildInternal(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:823)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocatedProject(MavenMetadataSource.java:163)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.InvalidProjectModelException: Parse error reading POM. Reason: end tag not allowed in epilog but got / (position: END_TAG seen ...</properties>\r\n\r\n</project>\r\n   </... @639:6)  for project org.apache.commons:commons-parent at C:\Users\kmilyutin\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-parent\11\commons-parent-11.pom
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1610)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1571)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:562)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.assembleLineage(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1392)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException: end tag not allowed in epilog but got / (position: END_TAG seen ...</properties>\r\n\r\n</project>\r\n   </... @639:6) 
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.parseEpilog(MXParser.java:1594)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1405)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1105)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.parseModel(MavenXpp3Reader.java:2133)
    at org.apache.maven.model.io.xpp3.MavenXpp3Reader.read(MavenXpp3Reader.java:3912)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1606)
    ... 44 more

Total time: 5 seconds
```

Here is part of `classpath.build.xml` (line 33 is `artifact:dependencies` tag):

```
<target name="resolve-dependencies" depends="checkTimestamps,mvn-configure"
            unless="${dependencies-resolved}">
        <macrodef name="resolve-scoped-dependencies" xmlns:artifact="urn:maven-artifact-ant">
            <attribute name="scope" />
            <sequential>
                <artifact:dependencies pathId="@{scope}.classpath" filesetId="@{scope}.fileset" useScope="@{scope}" >
                    <pom refid="maven.project" />
                    <localRepository refid="local.repository" />
                </artifact:dependencies>
                <pathconvert property="@{scope}.p" refid="@{scope}.fileset" pathsep="," />
                <echo file="target/@{scope}.fileset.txt">${@{scope}.p}</echo>
            </sequential>
        </macrodef>
        <resolve-scoped-dependencies scope="compile" />
        <resolve-scoped-dependencies scope="runtime" />
        <resolve-scoped-dependencies scope="provided" />
        <resolve-scoped-dependencies scope="system" />
        <resolve-scoped-dependencies scope="test" />
    </target>
```

Comment: simply delete `C:\Users\kmilyutin\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\` and retry your build.

Comment: If you still experience the issue, run maven with debug turned on (`mvn -X`) and add output to the question.

Comment: What kind of files `classpath.build.xml:33` is this? Not from a maven build ? Can you show the full pom file ?

Comment: I printed the debug output. Maven is called from Ant, I don't know the details, cause I'm not a Maven profi.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It says the reason in the message:

> Cannot find parent: org.apache.commons:commons-parent for project:
>   commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0

To be able to figure out the dependencies, maven not only needs the actual artifact metadata, but dependent metadata as well. That's what you're missing.

Since the commons-parent 11 [required by commons-beanutils 1.8](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.pom) is in [maven central repo](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.commons|commons-parent|11|pom), a retry with proper network connection to maven central should fix this.

However, if it does not, post the full output with debug turned on (`mvn -X`).

---

Edit: now with debug output, we can see that

C:\Users\kmilyutin.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-parent\11\commons-parent-11.pom

is broken:

```
org.apache.maven.project.InvalidProjectModelException: Parse error reading POM.
Reason: end tag not allowed in epilog but got / (position: END_TAG seen ...</properties>\r\n\r\n</project>\r\n   </... @639:6)
for project org.apache.commons:commons-parent
at C:\Users\kmilyutin\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-parent\11\commons-parent-11.pom
```

As a first action, remove that file from your local repo in the path given in the message and retry the build.

Comment: I think I have the connection to maven central repository, otherwise I wouldn't have all other files in `.m2\` directory, would I? How could I check this for sure?

Comment: @damluar that depends. You might have a connection to a proxy repo that only contains some of the stuff maven central has, for example. But you'd know if you use debug output.

Comment: @damluar your debug output shows that the parent pom is broken. I updated my answer based on that.

Comment: After removal of the file you specified, everything is building correctly. Do you have any guess why could it happen?

Comment: There are lot of alternatives, possibly a manual error, a hiccup in network connectivity or something else. It should be quite rare though. However, there are also several other reasons why local maven repo can have incorrect contents, so with maven and dependency troubles it is often that I retry with a clean repo.